# Returning an object by value which should conceptually not be copied

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, return-value-optimization

I'd like to have an object whose constructor acts as a `begin()` and it's destructor acts as an `end()`, and provides functions that are only valid between these two calls as methods. However... I also want to use named constructors, and also have functions that act as factories for this object too.

```cpp
// this is the object I'm returning by value
class DrawCommand {
    DrawCommand(CanvasBuffer & guts, uint32 threadID); // private
public:
    // begin(); starts  a draw command
    static DrawCommand inMT(Canvas & canvas);     // for main thread
    static DrawCommand inWK(const Job & jobRef);  // for worker threads

    // end(); submits command to rendering thread
    ~DrawCommand(); 

    // returns false if draw can be ignored (doesn't need to be respected)
    operator bool();

    // commands which would break if used outside of begin() and end()
    void doStuff();
};

// this class has a factory that returns by value
class Canvas{
public:
    DrawCommand debugDrawCommandMT(){
        DrawCommand cmd;
        ...
        return cmd;
    }
};

// usage
{
    DrawCommand cmd1 = DrawCommand::inMT(canvas);
    cmd1.doStuff();
} // cmd1.~DrawCommand() upon exiting scope

if (DrawCommand cmd2 = canvas.debugDrawCommandMT()) {
    cmd2.doStuff();
} // cmd2.~DrawCommand() upon exiting scope
```

This means returning this object by value.

This is troublesome as RVO is an optional optimization with side effects.  When omitted, this prompts calls to the constructor and destructor.  These functions are expensive as they access resources guarded by mutex, so I need to avoid that behavior.

What is the easiest way to ensure this object behaves as if RVO is always taking place when returned?

To be specific, what I'm after is the *behavior* of RVO, I've been able to find information on what it is and how to hint it's usage to the compiler.  But I want to get the side-effect of RVO in a reliable way.  Conceptually, it should be as if the object returned isn't a copy, but the original, even if that's not reality.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. 

Specially relevant is this : Since C++17, Return value optimization is mandatory and no longer considered as copy elision; see above. (Older versions its optional)

Comment: @PepijnKramer - thank you for the link, it's a dense read so it'll take me a moment, but "mandatory elision" is a very promising header (also sadly I'm stuck with C++14)

Comment: Yeah its a lot of standardeze, but sometimes if you really need to know what happens there is nothing to it but to read it (and read it again later).

Comment: make `DrawCommand` movable instead?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was thinking something like that. Or you could return a "Wrapper" (kind of like pimpl) that's cheap to copy/move. And just forwards to the implementation e.g. if you're lazy a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr if you want to work with std::move explicitly. I've done that kind of thing before to. It lets the caller think it has some solid object and you hade the memory managment from them that way.

Comment: You could make `DrawCommand` a move only type. If `DrawCommand` doesn't have any state that you could use to determine if the object was moved from, you could implement a flag. So, in the `move` ctor/operator you could set the flag in the object being moved from which signifies that the object has been moved from. Then in the dtor of `DrawCommand` check if the flag is set. if set, don't send the command to the rendering thread.

Comment: @WBuck - Like `Foo::Foo(Foo && other)`?  I'll freely admit that move/assignment/copy constructors are really confusing to me, I know vaguely there's a rule where you need 3... or 5 of them?  Iunno, but if I have that method, transfer the state over and invalidate `other` so it's ~Foo() is harmless, would that fly?

Comment: Yeah, check something in the dtor to see the of object was moved from. If it was, then don’t send the command to the sender thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I had in mind.
You can run this and see the console output.

It's a moveable only type (if you attempt to copy you'll see a compiler error about a deleted function).

It prevents sending the command to the thread if the object has been moved from.

```
class DrawCommand { 
public:
    explicit DrawCommand( std::string state ) noexcept
        : state_{ std::move( state ) }
        , moved_{ false }
    { }

    DrawCommand( const DrawCommand& ) = delete;
    DrawCommand& operator=( const DrawCommand& ) = delete;

    DrawCommand( DrawCommand&& other ) noexcept 
        : state_{ std::exchange( other.state_, { } ) }
        , moved_{ std::exchange( other.moved_, true ) }
    { } 

    DrawCommand& operator=( DrawCommand&& other ) noexcept { 
        state_ = std::exchange( other.state_, { } );
        moved_ = std::exchange( other.moved_, true );
        return *this;
    }

    ~DrawCommand( ) {
        if ( moved_ ) std::cout << "Skip sending to thread\n";
        else std::cout << "Sending " << state_ << '\n';
     }
private:
    std::string state_;
    bool moved_;
};

static auto create_command( ) -> DrawCommand { 
    return DrawCommand{ "Some state" };
}

auto main( ) -> int { 
    { 
        auto cmd{ create_command( ) };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant, but then in code:
(If needed change to shared_ptr and forget about move constructor and just use copy constructor)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ClassItf
{
public:
    virtual ~ClassItf() = default;

    virtual void DoWork() = 0;

protected:
    ClassItf(const ClassItf&) = delete;
    ClassItf(ClassItf&&) = delete;
    ClassItf& operator=(ClassItf&) = delete;
    ClassItf() = default;
};

// hide implementation 
namespace details
{
class ImplementationClass :
    public ClassItf
{
public:
    ImplementationClass()
    {
        std::cout << "ImplementationClass::ImplementationClass" << std::endl;
    }

    ~ImplementationClass()
    {
        std::cout << "ImplementationClass::~ImplementationClass" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void DoWork() override
    {
        std::cout << "ImplementationClass::DoWork" << std::endl;
    }
};
}

class YourClass :
    public ClassItf
{
public:
    YourClass() :
        m_impl{ std::make_unique<details::ImplementationClass>() }
    {
    }

    YourClass(YourClass&& other) :
        m_impl{ std::move(other.m_impl) }
    {
        std::cout << "YourClass::YourClass moved" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void DoWork() override
    {
        m_impl->DoWork();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ClassItf> m_impl;
};

YourClass CreateClass()
{
    YourClass retval;
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto obj = CreateClass();
        obj.DoWork();
    }
    std::cout << "Done..." << std::endl;
}
```